# Call OAuth1 api with RestSharp, using a parameter range not working

Tags: c#, parameters, oauth, restsharp

I have a problem using RestSharp, when calling an API using OAuth1. The problem only happens when I need to use a parameter with a range and not if I use a normal parameter.

Normal parameter:

example.com/something?active=true

Parameter with range:

www.example.com/something?range(1,100)

The code I'm using is:

```
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl)
        {
            Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken("ConsumerKey", "ConsumerSecret")
        };
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
return client.Execute(request);
```

I cannot add the range parameter as a parameter with the following:

```
request.AddParameter("range", "(1,100)");
```

Because then the request will be:

example.com/something?range=(1,100)

And I cannot add the parameter to the URL (baseUrl), because then I get the following response:

> Using query parameters in the base URL is not supported for OAuth
>   calls. Consider using AddDefaultQueryParameter instead.

Any ideas about what to do?

Comment: I think there are 2 things - one you need to see the API controller and second you are expecting the API to behave the same way as actual web url which may or may notbe correct

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. And see if I can read up on this.

Comment: no worries, you must see the API controller any json model building on that, if you still need help, mention me and add the controller details in the question